# Unable to call or execute a VBA sub in Applescript for powerpoint mac 2011

Tags: macos, vba, applescript, ms-office

I seem to be unable to call or execute a VBA sub in Applescript for PowerPoint Mac 2011. This works fine for office powerpoint 2004

Here is my code:

```
on run {paramVBAScript}
    with timeout of 5 seconds
        tell application "System Events"
            if not (exists process "Microsoft PowerPoint") then return ""
        end tell
    tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    set vbaScript to the command bar control "XXXXX" of command bar ¬
        "Help" of command bar "Menu Bar"

            set parameter of vbaScript to paramVBAScript
            **execute vbaScript** 

            set retValue to parameter of vbaScript
            return retValue
    end tell

end timeout

Execute Vbascript is not working 
end run
```

Where can I be going wrong?

Comment: I think this question needs some editing to make it legible.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft discontinued VBA support in the Mac version of office after v2004. You need to port your VBA to Applescript in order to do what you want.

Comment: No, VBA support was removed in Office for Mac 2008 but restored in Office for Mac 2011.

Comment: @idontwanttortfm: Like I wrote "...*after* v2004." (And Office 2011 was released over three months *after* this answer was posted.) If you have a better answer, I highly suggest posting it as opposed to just commenting so you at least get credit.

Comment: He's asking specifically about Office 2011 so I wanted it to be clear that, in the version he's asking about, VBA is supported. I don't have an answer to his question because it's not clear what he's trying to do; I just wanted to make sure people didn't get the wrong idea about VBA support in Office 2011.